# Unstable BLE Connection in Android 6 (Marshmallow)

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, rssi

I'm developing an android app that works with Bluetooth LE. It works well on Android 4.3 or 5.0.1 and on various devices, but in Android M (6.0.1) it isn't stable. I wrote a lite sample project that has same behavior and issues, and below is my all code;

```
@TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP)
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {
    private BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter;
    private int REQUEST_ENABLE_BT = 1;
    private Handler mHandler;
    private static final long SCAN_PERIOD = 2000;
    private BluetoothLeScanner mLEScanner;
    private ScanSettings settings;
    private List<ScanFilter> filters;
    private BluetoothGatt mGatt;

    private boolean connectionState = false, isScanning = false;
    private TextView rssiTxt;
    private RSSITimer rssiTimer;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mHandler = new Handler();
        if (!getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_BLUETOOTH_LE)) {
            Toast.makeText(this, "BLE Not Supported",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            finish();
        }
        final BluetoothManager bluetoothManager =
                (BluetoothManager) getSystemService(Context.BLUETOOTH_SERVICE);
        mBluetoothAdapter = bluetoothManager.getAdapter();

        // VIEW
        rssiTxt = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rssiTxt);

        (rssiTimer = new RSSITimer()).startTimer();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null || !mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            Intent enableBtIntent = new Intent(BluetoothAdapter.ACTION_REQUEST_ENABLE);
            startActivityForResult(enableBtIntent, REQUEST_ENABLE_BT);
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 21) {
                mLEScanner = mBluetoothAdapter.getBluetoothLeScanner();
                settings = new ScanSettings.Builder()
                        .setScanMode(ScanSettings.SCAN_MODE_LOW_LATENCY)
                        .build();
                filters = new ArrayList<ScanFilter>();
            }
            scanLeDevice(true);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        if (mBluetoothAdapter != null && mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
            //scanLeDevice(false);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        rssiTimer.stopTimerTask();

        if (mGatt == null) {
            return;
        }
        mGatt.close();
        mGatt = null;
        super.onDestroy();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_ENABLE_BT) {
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
                //Bluetooth not enabled.
                finish();
                return;
            }
        }
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    }

    private void scanLeDevice(final boolean enable) {
        if(isScanning) {
            return;
        } else {
            isScanning = true;
        }

        if (enable) {
            mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                        mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);

                        isScanning = false;
                    } else {
                        mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);

                        isScanning = false;
                    }
                }
            }, SCAN_PERIOD);
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.startLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            } else {
                mLEScanner.startScan(filters, settings, mScanCallback);
            }
        } else {
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < 21) {
                mBluetoothAdapter.stopLeScan(mLeScanCallback);
            } else {
                mLEScanner.stopScan(mScanCallback);
            }
        }
    }

    private ScanCallback mScanCallback = new ScanCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onScanResult(int callbackType, ScanResult result) {
            Log.i("callbackType", String.valueOf(callbackType));
            Log.i("result", result.toString());
            BluetoothDevice btDevice = result.getDevice();

            if ("PRODi".equals(device.getName()) || "PRODi(TEST)".equals(device.getName())) {
                connectToDevice(btDevice);
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onBatchScanResults(List<ScanResult> results) {
            for (ScanResult sr : results) {
                Log.i("ScanResult - Results", sr.toString());
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onScanFailed(int errorCode) {
            Log.e("Scan Failed", "Error Code: " + errorCode);
        }
    };

    private BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback mLeScanCallback =
            new BluetoothAdapter.LeScanCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onLeScan(final BluetoothDevice device, int rssi,
                                     byte[] scanRecord) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.i("onLeScan", device.toString());

                            if ("PRODi".equals(device.getName()) || "PRODi(TEST)".equals(device.getName())) {
                                connectToDevice(device);
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };

    public void connectToDevice(BluetoothDevice device) {
        if (mGatt == null) {
            mGatt = device.connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), false, gattCallback);
            scanLeDevice(false);// will stop after first device detection

            return;
        } else {
            mGatt.connect();
            scanLeDevice(false);// will stop after first device detection
        }
    }

    private final BluetoothGattCallback gattCallback = new BluetoothGattCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onConnectionStateChange(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status, int newState) {
            switch (newState) {
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_CONNECTED:

                    Log.i("gattCallback", "STATE_CONNECTED");
                    gatt.discoverServices();
                    connectionState = true;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "STATE_CONNECTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                case BluetoothProfile.STATE_DISCONNECTED:

                    Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_DISCONNECTED");
                    connectionState = false;
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "STATE_DISCONNECTED", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
                    break;
                default:
                    Log.e("gattCallback", "STATE_OTHER");
            }

        }

        @Override
        public void onServicesDiscovered(BluetoothGatt gatt, int status) {
            List<BluetoothGattService> services = gatt.getServices();
            Log.i("onServicesDiscovered", services.toString());
            gatt.readCharacteristic(services.get(1).getCharacteristics().get(0));
        }

        @Override
        public void onCharacteristicRead(BluetoothGatt gatt,
                                         BluetoothGattCharacteristic
                                                 characteristic, int status) {
            Log.i("onCharacteristicRead", characteristic.toString());
            gatt.disconnect();
        }

        @Override
        public void onReadRemoteRssi(BluetoothGatt gatt, int rssi, int status) {
            super.onReadRemoteRssi(gatt, rssi, status);

            final int rssi2 = rssi;
            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    rssiTxt.setText("RSSI: " + rssi2);
                }
            });
        }
    };

    /*TIMER for Read RSSI*/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
    class RSSITimer {
        //we are going to use a handler to be able to run in our TimerTask
        final Handler handler = new Handler();
        private Timer     timer;
        private TimerTask timerTask;

        private int interval = 1000;

        public void startTimer() {
            //set a new Timer
            timer = new Timer();
            //initialize the TimerTask's job
            initializeTimerTask();
            //schedule the timer, after the first 1000ms the TimerTask will run every [INTERVAL]ms
            timer.schedule(timerTask, 1000, interval); //
        }

        public void stopTimerTask() {
            //stop the timer, if it's not already null
            if (timer != null)
            {
                timer.cancel();
                timer = null;
            }
        }

        public void initializeTimerTask() {
            timerTask = new TimerTask() {
                public void run() {
                    handler.post(new Runnable() {
                        public void run() {

                            if (mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                                if (connectionState == false) {
                                    scanLeDevice(true);
                                } else {
                                    mGatt.readRemoteRssi();
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
```

It have this various issues;

- don't receive callback of readRemoteRssi() after few seconds
- don't connect again, after disconnect
- don't work when application goes to background
- bluetooth chip resets between disconnect and trying to connect again!!
- ...

I know that `DeadObjectException` occured in `BluetthGatt` during this issues and `readRemoteRssi()` returned false, but can't solve it.

I know that Android 6 have some changes in BLE and I searched a lot and Studied Documents, but no result! But I found that when I set the `interval` to `100` instead of `1000`, it works BETTER, but not Absolutely (on Android 6.0.1). Yes, I am sure that `interval` and how to implement it (Runnable, AlarmManager, TimerTask, ScheduledExecutorService, ...) are effective to that, but WHY?! It's my qustion.

Have anybody idea? Thanks and Sorry about my English.

UPDATE: Here is [a link](http://www.mediafire.com/download/zgv9ezel1ajl2vj/ble_log.txt) to my log, when I put appliction under some pressure. Sorry, it is bigger than stackoverflow capacity!! I see clearly that Bluetooth restarted in it...

Comment: File a bug report on Android's bug tracker.

Comment: What is this mean? I mean, is my code and approach clean? Did you test it or you experienced this problem?!

Answer (score 1):

Enable "Bluetooth HCI snoop log" and use [Wireshark](https://www.wireshark.org/download.html) to analyze packets.
This way you can see Bluetooth stack events.
[Bluetooth HCI snoop log Menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EhEow.png)

Answer (score 0):

> don't connect again, after disconnect

Execute device.connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), true, gattCallback); instead of device.connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), false, gattCallback); to automatically reconnect.

> don't work when application goes to background

You need to have a foreground service or something else in your application process that prevents your process from being killed. This is because the BLE apis are based on callbacks and not intents.

> bluetooth chip reset between disconnect and trying to connect again!!
>   don't receive callback of readRemoteRssi() after few seconds

Definitely a bug in Android. File a bug report. Could you post the FULL logcat output (not only the output filtered from your application)?

> don't receive callback of readRemoteRssi() after few seconds

No idea about this one...

Comment: First, thanks for your attention. I tryed `device.connectGatt(getApplicationContext(), true, gattCallback)` before, without result! And about `don't work when application goes to background`, I mean press Home Button and touch application without delay and without any other application that consume memory. My orginal project uses Services for background running.
Anyway, what is your opinion about `Shutting down VM` in logcat? Also I updated my logcat.

Comment: Shutting down VM is done because your app throws an exception which is unhandled. You shouldn't do device.getName().equals("PRODi") in your scan handler - getName() might return null if the advertising data does not contain any name. Instead do "PRODi".equals(device.getName()) since that never throws an exception.

Comment: You are right about this case, but it is not root of my problems (on Android 6). I will put new logs...

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are scanning and connecting/reading/writing at the same time. On Android this leads to stability problems and the bluetooth stack can crash. Try to go easier on the bluetooth stack, never scan and connect at the same time, only connect to one device and wait until the callbacks returned before doing the next thing, you should even add some breaks between your ble tasks.
We had a lot of issues when doing too much on the ble stack at the same time, like a crashing bluetooth stack, not able to connect to devices anymore until you restart the device and so on.

Comment: I read rssi again in `onReadRemoteRssi()` callback (with postDelay), but no effect! When I remove reading rssi entirely, everything is OK!

Comment: You could use the scan to get RSSI values, if that helps.

Comment: For connected device, `onLecan()` or `onScanResult()` don't be triggered.

Comment: I couldn't find anything in the logs, but perhaps reading the RSSI fails because the device is disconnected. Sometimes a device disconnects after some time. You should stop the RssiTimer once you are disconnected.

Comment: So why I'm not receiving `onConnectionStateChange` callback?!

Comment: Probably because the Bluetooth stack restarted. Do you have multiple devices  with Android 6? If so is the behaviour on all phones the same? If not have you the possibility to test on another Marshmallow device? Could be a device specific problem.

Comment: I hava two deices with Marshmallow on it, and same behaviour (Not exactly, but both of them have similar problems). I have Galaxy S6 with official update for Android 6.0.1 and Galaxy S4 with Cyanogen Android 6.0.1!

Comment: I tested now with a Sony Z5 and a Samsung S6 both with Android 6.0.1, I removed the call to gatt.disconnect in the onCharacteristicRead() callback and it works just fine. I used another Android phone as a peripheral. Do I need to wait for a longer time until this happens?

Comment: I removed it, It was not necessary for me, and nothing changed. I think you must wait longer. Did you have my problems on your phones before this change?
Anyway, thanks for your attention!

Comment: I will try it again tomorrow as I am currently in a hurry. I tried your example without the change and it worked also, it just disconnected and reconnected between reading the rssi. Do you connect to another Android smartphone or to something else?

Comment: No, just connect to single ble dongle.

Comment: Maybe your ble dongle could be the issue, I had now your app running for 1.5h and it is still reading the rssi.